# Python cat, aka Unix Meow

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, unix

I have used linux and Windows interchangeably over the last time, and I got used to the more comfortable and options-rich syntax of linux' commands, so I decided to replicate some of them in python (with some modification) so I can use them in Windows, and started with the `ls` and `cat` commands [after adding their parent dir under `PATH` and associating `py` files with python, they can be used like the originals].

I built `cat` with almost the same features as the original (see [linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html)), with the addition of the `-r REPEAT` option that repeats every file `REPEAT` times (default 1), and the `-f` header option that prints the file name before every file (like windows' `TYPE`), and the interpretation of filenames other than `-` as file patterns - that will expand to cover all matching files, on cases like `cat *s*.*`. All of the `nbAeEtTv` options function the same.

I have been using python for a while now, and tried to make the code as efficient and "pythonic" as I could. However, I still believe there is a **lot** of room for improvements, let alone some issues as the need to scan the files before the printing loop on numbering mode to assure number format adjustment.

---

#### Here is my code:

```
import argparse, shutil, sys
import itertools
import os, os.path
import string, glob, re


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='concatenate files and print on the standard output')

    parser.add_argument('filenames', nargs='+', help='directory to scan')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--repeat', dest='repeat', default=1, type=int, help='repeat output multiple times')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--header', dest='header', default=False, help='precede every file with its name', action='store_true')

    parser.add_argument('-n', '--number', dest='number', default=False, help='number all output lines', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--number-nonblank', dest='number_nonblank', default=False, help='number nonempty output lines', action='store_true')

    parser.add_argument('-A', '--show-all', dest='show_all', default=False, help='equivalent to -vET', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-e', dest='show_ends_and_nonprinting', default=False, help='equivalent to -vE', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-E', '--show-ends', dest='show_ends', default=False, help='display $ at end of each line', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-t', dest='show_tabs_and_nonprinting', default=False, help='equivalent to -vT', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-T', '--show-tabs', dest='show_tabs', default=False, help='display TAB characters as ^I', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--show-nonprinting', dest='show_nonprinting', default=False, help='use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB', action='store_true')

    args = parser.parse_args()


    # Special chars option overlapping
    args.show_tabs = args.show_tabs or args.show_tabs_and_nonprinting or args.show_all
    args.show_ends = args.show_ends or args.show_ends_and_nonprinting or args.show_all
    args.show_nonprinting = args.show_nonprinting or args.show_tabs_and_nonprinting or args.show_ends_and_nonprinting or args.show_all

    # Special chars definitions
    tabs = '^I' if args.show_tabs else '\t'
    ends = '$\n' if args.show_ends else '\n'
    nonprinting = {k: '^' + v for k, v in zip(range(32), '@'+ string.ascii_uppercase + '[\]^!') if v not in 'IJ'} if args.show_nonprinting else {}


    # Set filenames by provided patterns
    GET_INPUT = 0
    args.filenames = list(itertools.chain(*([GET_INPUT] if filepattern == '-' else glob.glob(filepattern) for filepattern in args.filenames)))


    # Numbering settings
    if args.number or args.number_nonblank:
        line_number = 1
        longest_line_number_length = len(str((sum(open(filename, 'rb').read().count(b'\n') if filename != GET_INPUT else 1 for filename in args.filenames) + 1) * args.repeat))

    # The printing loop(s)
    for filename in args.filenames:

        if filename == GET_INPUT:
            print(input())
            continue

        if args.header:
            print('{:=^{}}'.format(filename, shutil.get_terminal_size().columns // 2))

        for _ in range(args.repeat):
            with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
                for line in file:
                    nonblank_line = re.match('.*\S.*', line.decode(errors='replace'))
                    print(
                        '    {:>{}}  '.format(line_number, longest_line_number_length) if args.number or (args.number_nonblank and nonblank_line) \
                            else ' ' * (longest_line_number_length + 6) if args.number_nonblank else '', # For -E under -b
                        line.decode(errors='backslashreplace').rstrip('\n\r').replace('\t', tabs).translate(nonprinting),
                        sep='', end=ends
                    )
                    if args.number or (args.number_nonblank and nonblank_line):
                        line_number += 1
```

---

#### Demo:

> ```
> C:\Dev>dump a -t
> 000000000000 │ 31 32 33 34   35                                      │ 12345
>
> C:\Dev>dump b -t
> 000000000000 │ 04 09 41 42   43 44 45 46                             │ ..ABCDEF
>
> C:\Dev>echo 789 | cat a - b >> c
>
> C:\Dev>cat c -Anr2
>     1  12345$
>     2  789 $
>     3  ^D^IABCDEF$
>     4  12345$
>     5  789 $
>     6  ^D^IABCDEF$
> ```

---

```
    _                ___       _.--.
    \`.|\..----...-'`   `-._.-'_.-'`
    /  ' `         ,       __.--'
    )/' _/     \   `-_,   /
    `-'" `"\_  ,_.-;_.-\_ ',
        _.-'_./   {_.'   ; /
       {_.-``-'         {_/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least the code is not at the top-level of the file, but you should really use functions to document what is going on. Well chosen names can go a long way into conveying what you are doing and why.

I also have a tendency to extract out the `argparse` machinery out of the way of the actual computation. This way, I can mock this part in my tests:

```
>>> class Args:
...   def __getattr__(self, key):
...     return None
... 
>>> args = Args()
>>> args.foo
>>> args.spam = 'egg'
>>> args.bacon = 'foo'
>>> vars(args)
{'spam': 'egg', 'bacon': 'foo'}
```

and call `main(args)` (or in your case `cat(args)`) without having to rely on the command-line. So lets build that:

```
def parse_command_line():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description='concatenate files and print on the standard output')

    parser.add_argument('filenames', nargs='+', help='directory to scan')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--repeat', dest='repeat', default=1, type=int,
                        help='repeat output multiple times')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--header', dest='header', default=False,
                        help='precede every file with its name',
                        action='store_true')

    parser.add_argument('-n', '--number', dest='number', default=False,
                        help='number all output lines', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--number-nonblank', dest='number_nonblank',
                        default=False, help='number nonempty output lines',
                        action='store_true')

    parser.add_argument('-A', '--show-all', dest='show_all', default=False,
                        help='equivalent to -vET', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-e', dest='show_ends_and_nonprinting', default=False,
                        help='equivalent to -vE', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-E', '--show-ends', dest='show_ends', default=False,
                        help='display $ at end of each line', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-t', dest='show_tabs_and_nonprinting', default=False,
                        help='equivalent to -vT', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-T', '--show-tabs', dest='show_tabs', default=False,
                        help='display TAB characters as ^I', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--show-nonprinting', dest='show_nonprinting',
                        default=False, action='store_true',
                        help='use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB')

    args = parser.parse_args()


    # Special chars option overlapping
    if args.show_all:
        args.show_tabs = True
        args.show_ends = True
        args.show_nonprinting = True
    if args.show_tabs_and_nonprinting:
        args.show_tabs = True
        args.show_nonprinting = True
    if args.show_ends_and_nonprinting:
        args.show_ends = True
        args.show_nonprinting = True
    if args.number_nonblank:
        args.number = True  # See later why

    return args
```

I also inverted a bit the management of overlapping options as I feel it reads better.

This way, even if you put the rest of the code into a single `def cat(args):` function, the main part is down to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_command_line()
    cat(args)
```

which should be much easier to start testing.

---

Now, as regard to the core of your program, I can see at least 2 undocumented behaviour that differ from the `cat` utility on linux. First of, you’re only ever reading one line of input instead of the whole `stdin`. Consider use cases like `grep PATTERN unfiltered.txt | cat header.txt - footer.txt` that the original `cat` handles perfectly (*i.e.* all of the output of `grep` is printed between the content of `header.txt` and `footer.txt`). You don't. Since I also don't understand why you would repeat every other files but `stdin`, I suggest using [the `tempfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) to buffer the content of `stdin`.

We will thus need to change the content of the input array, so let's encapsulate that in a function that perform the globing too, to clean up this `chain` command. While I’m at it, `cat` also allow to specify no filename on the command line, which is treated the same as a single `'-'` so let's fix that as well:

```
def sanitize_filenames(file_patterns):
    for pattern in file_patterns:
        if pattern == '-':
            yield buffer_stdin()
        else:
            yield from glob.glob(pattern)

    if not file_patterns:
        yield buffer_stdin()


def buffer_stdin():
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as stdin:
        for line in sys.stdin:
            stdin.write(line)
    return stdin.name
```

Usage being: `filenames = list(sanitize_filenames(args.filenames))`. However, this implementation leave a file in the temporary directory for each `'-'` present on the command line; I’ll get to it latter.

The second behaviour that differs is the way you handle line counts on `-n` or `-b` options. `cat` uses the equivalent of `'{:>6}\t'.format(line_number)` to prepend them when needed; making the alignment between line 999999 and 1000000 go:

```
999999  one line
1000000 another line
```

and the one between line 9999999 and 10000000 go:

```
9999999 one line
10000000    another line
```

If you made the same, you could simplify the code a bit by not having to read each file upfront.

You also handle `-Eb` a "better" way than `cat` which just remove the formatting altogether:

```
9999999 one line$
$
10000000    another line$
```

I’ll try to keep that. I would however change the way you handle nonprinting characters because the special cases `I` and `J` are in fact handling of tabs and newlines. So I'd use a single `translate` instead of `replace` + `translate`.

```
def prepend_line_numbers(numbers):
    print('{:>6}\t'.format(numbers), end='')


def build_special_chars_table(args):
    table = {
        9: '^I' if args.show_tabs else '\t',
        10: '$' if args.show_ends else '',
    }
    if args.show_nonprinting:
        nonprinting_representation = '@{}[\]^!'.format(string.ascii_uppercase)
        table.update({
            k: '^' + v
            for k, v in enumerate(nonprinting_representation)
            if v not in 'IJ'
        })
    return table


def cat(args):
    nonprinting = build_special_chars_table(args)
    header_width = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns // 2
    line_count = 0
    for filename in sanitize_filenames(args.filenames):
        if args.header:
            print('{:=^{}}'.format(filename, header_width))

        for _ in range(args.repeat):
            with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
                for line in file:
                    blank_line = not line.rstrip()
                    if not (args.number_nonblank and blank_line):
                        line_count += 1
                        if args.number:
                            prepend_line_numbers(line_count)
                    elif args.number:  # Useful there to have that True even when -b only
                        # For -E under -b
                        prepend_line_numbers(' ' * len(str(line_count)))
                    print(line
                            .decode(errors='backslashreplace')
                            .translate(nonprinting))
```

---

Now to get back on the files staying on disc after that utily ran over some `'-'` on the command line, you can define a class like:

```
class StdInWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as stdin:
            self.name = stdin.name
            for line in sys.stdin:
                stdin.write(line)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def remove(self):
        os.remove(self.name)
```

instead of the `buffer_stdin` function. You would need to change the call to `open(filename, 'rb')` into `open(str(filename), 'rb')` so that it still work and figure a way to call remove on that object at the end of the repetitions.

Comment: I'll just suggest adding `13: ''` to the table, to avoid printing `$` in the beginning of the line (after the carriage return) instead of it's normal place in Windows (where newline is usually `\r\n`). The rest is just awesome, thanks!